# (JSoup) How to compare user input and HTML to see the text exist or not

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I would like my program to be able to find a particular text on HTML using JSoup

For example, a user key in "ABC" and using JSoup to parse the HTML element to check whether the user input exist on the HTML code or not and return error messages if it doesn't exist.

The tag that I'm finding the text is at this line below

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://forum.lowyat.net/user/ABC"/>
```

Sorry if my question is not clear. Please do give feedback if don't understand.

Comment: Your scenerio is totally unclear to me. You are talking about inputs, but showing in exapmle `<link>`. Clearify plz.

Comment: What my question is I have an user input for example "ABC". What I want to do is to find whether the string "ABC" exist on the page or not. And I'm finding the string "ABC" is at `<link rel="canonical" href="https://forum.lowyat.net/user/ABC"/>` line.

Comment: Much better now. Not should it be in some tag property (like in `href` value in example) or in text only?

Comment: What you mean by "tag property"? User input is just a normal string.

Comment: `<input>`, `<link>` those are tags. Every tag can have its properties eg.`<input type='hidden' name='my_val'>` - here `type` and `name` are properties(attributes to be exact) of `input` tag. Now where are you want to look for a match? In tag properties, or in text content?

Comment: I want to look for a match at the attributes. On the `href` part.

Comment: that exactly what i have been asking (now I am assuming you are interested only in `href`s :)) now let me think... For futore, familiarize yourself with selector api: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to search that one type of Element, you can simply loop through all of them and check if the href tag contains the user query:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(YOUR_HTML_SOURCE);

String userInput = "ABC";
Elements imports = doc.select("link");
    for (Element e : imports) {
        if (link.tagName("href").toString().contains(userInput)) {
            System.out.println(link.toString()); // this element contains it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to our litle chat in comments I assume that you are looking for every `tag` with `href` attribute containing user input. For this, simple sigle line cat do the trick. Check it out!

First of all, you are interested in this line from Selector API documentation:

> [attr*=valContaining]     elements with an attribute named "attr", and value containing "valContaining"

ok so lets go to work

```
Document doc=Jsoup.parse(somePage) // or connect or whatever. The point is that doc is of Document type.
Elements elements=doc.select(String.format("[href*=%s]",userInput));
if(elements.isEmpty()){
    //sorry, there was no such thing on a page
}else{
     // elements is the collection of all tags containing href attribute that contains provided user input
    //do something with those elements
}
```

and that is preatty it!